# Is the Fermi golden rule really accurate for calculating the life time of an atomic level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, perturbation-theory, approximations, fermis-golden-rule

In my impression, [Fermi golden rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi's_golden_rule) is routinely used in calculating the life time of an excited atomic level.

But it is based on the first order perturbation theory, so it is not expected to be very accurate, right?

Is there any example of large deviation from experiment?

Comment: As with all perturbative methods the question to ask is *"How big an error do I make by truncating the series here?"* Hint: for an atomic system the coupling is electromagnetic.

Comment: The problem in practice is not so much the first order theory, but that we don't know the proper base functions very well and that the problem turns relativistic after hydrogen very quickly. Hydrogen is a very misleading, but fortunate, singular case where the theory is simple and can be analyzed in closed form. For other atoms and molecules that's not the case.

Comment: http://www.nat.vu.nl/~tvisser/nonexponential.pdf

Comment: @CuriousOne You mean there is not sufficient data for comparison?

Comment: This question (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: I might suggest that your impression is wrong, in general. In early physics classes that might seem the case. It remains an easy guess to make and formula to remember.